# Replace a character before another character in any line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

As an example, I have the following lines:

```
"ac.dde.ddd"="ecc.cercer.";
"frf.ttg.hy"="gew.dfr.e.";
```

They should be exported as:

```
"ac_dde_ddd"="ecc.cercer.";
"frf_ttg_hy"="gew.dfr.e.";
```

I.e. the dots are replaced by '_' but before '=' only.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for:

```
\.(?=[^=\n]*=)
```

and replace by `_`

`(?=[^=\n]*=)` is a lookahead that means dot must be followed by at least `=`.

Comment: It is changing '.'s after '=' also, :(

Comment: See update, you can add `\n` in negation character class so that it doesn't go beyond one line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to only replace `_` before `=`:

Find what:

```
\.(?=.*?=)
```

Replace with:

```
_
```

With the *. matches newline* option OFF, `.*?` will match only characters on 1 line, as few as possible before a `=`.

Settings:

[image]